# How can i get the bottom center x,y of my image view in android?

Tags: android, imageview, coordinates

I have tried this code,

```
float blackCenterX = blackX +black.getWidth() / 2;
```

but what formula should I use if I am looking for the bottom center coordinates of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the Center|Bottom position of a View:

```
+-------+
| View  |
+---X---+
    |
    |___ (X = view.width / 2, Y = view.height)
```